# I get this error running PMD from salesforce CLI, "ERROR running scanner:run: Attempted to resolve unregistered dependency token: "RuleManager""

Tags: pmd

Can anyone help me with this. Im using Mac. I cant find the location of the rulemanager. Please see error below

Lxxxxxxx:pmd-bin-6.34.0 xxxxxx$ sfdx scanner:run pmd --target /usr/src --category rulesets/java/quickstart.xml -f sarif
(node:17810) [editions-autoloader-none-broadened] Error Plugin: sfdx-cli: editions-autoloader-none-broadened: Unable to determine a suitable edition, even after broadening.
module: @oclif/config@1.17.0
task: runHook init
plugin: sfdx-cli
root: /Users/xxxxxxx/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.100.0-9d243d8
See more details with DEBUG=*
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
ERROR running scanner:run:  Attempted to resolve unregistered dependency token: "RuleManager"

Answer (score 0):

Kieran, this is an issue that we just discovered. It is related to an incompatibility with the version of Node.js that is bundled with the Salesforce CLI and a library that is used by sfdx-scanner.

A temporary workaround can be found at https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-scanner/issues/412

You will need to use the npm installation instead of the pkg installer since you are interested in the Sarif output. Sarif output was added in version 2.6.0. The issue affects versions 2.6.0-2.8.0 when using the pkg installer on a Mac.

We hope to have a fix rolled out in the next couple of days. I will post here when version 2.9 has been released. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Kieran, this issue has been fixed in version 2.9.1. You can upgrade by executing the following commands in your shell.

sfdx plugins:uninstall @salesforce/sfdx-scanner

sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/sfdx-scanner